# Dynamic object manipulation in Powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, object, iron

I was trying my hand at the Iron Scripter challenge 3, which tasks us with crawling an RSS feed and retrieving pieces of info. I did this by capturing each element as a property of a new object using foreach. The problem I run into is this: Since I used a foreach, the objects do not have unique names, so I cannot call their individual properties. I'm looking for a method of uniquely identifying each object, so they can be called individually. Additionally, the $entry.creator output comes through as "creator", but if I just type in $entry.creator, the authors name shows properly.

```
[xml]$rss = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://powershell.org/feed'
$rss2 = $rss.rss.channel.item
$i = [int]1
foreach($entry in $rss2){
$out = New-Object PSObject -property @{
                    Number = $i++
                    Title = $entry.title
                    Date = $entry.pubDate
                    Link = $entry.link
                    Author = $entry.creator
             }
$out
 }
```

Comment: Why not just use the normal for? Like `for($n =0; $n -lt $rss2.Length; $n++) {$out=.. Title = $rss2.title[$n] ....}`

Comment: Also I dont really get the question about $entry.creator , but if I want to get the correct Informations about the author I had to call it like this `$rss2.creator[$n].'#cdata-section'`

Comment: As you can probably tell, I am still new to scripting and Powershell. I chose the foreach because there are multiple entries. Is that not necessary? I also figured I could capture the info as properties of an object so I could later add a menu and make that information available on command. I did try pasting in your response, but received errors:

Comment: .. : The term '..' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:4 char:45
+ for($n =0; $n -lt $rss2.Length; $n++) {$out=.. Title = $rss2.title[$n ...
+                                             ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (..:String) [], CommandNotFoundE 
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Well ok I though it was obvious that "$out=.." just was a filler because i didnt want to rewrite your whole code in a comment... :'D

Never the less I think I got your question wrong the first time. If you want to get certain Attributes from the rss you can call them like you just did with $rss2.<Attribute>[<position>]. For example $rss2.Title[0] if you want the Title of the first article.
If you want to Address the article without referring to their position with [<position>], you have to create an Hashtable with certain keys instead.

Comment: I don't think I explained the situation very well. My bad :). The goal of the exercise is to be able to display the parameters listed above (author, date, link, etc.) of each entry in the rss feed. Then, the user should be able to choose which entry they want and be able to either take them to the link or display the content of that entry. My script does the first part, but now that it is displaying , I am unsure how to allow the user to decide which entry they want to view.

Comment: And thanks for going easy on a newb.